# Not catching the unicorn timeout exception in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

This is sample code which i am trying to handle exception from unicorn.

**unicron.rb**

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true
```

**timeout.rb**

```
Rack::Timeout.timeout = 12
```

**Sample code**

```
def create_store
   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

     @store = Store.new(params[:store])
     if @store.save!
       sleep 12.3
       InformUserWorker.perform_async(store_id)
     end

   end

   rescue => exception
    exception.backtrace.each { |trace| puts trace }
   rescue Timeout::Error
    puts 'That took too long, exiting...1'
   rescue Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException
    puts 'That took too long, exiting...2'
   rescue Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutError
    puts 'That took too long, exiting...3'
   rescue Rack::Timeout::RequestExpiryError
    puts 'That took too long, exiting...4'
end
```

I am getting `code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"` with this sleep 12.3 seconds, and the transaction rollback happens, but none of these exceptions are executing. I have added couple of exception here. Anything goes wrong here?.

Answer (score 0):

Rescues are executed in order. So your first rescue captures anything that is being raised and the code never gets past that point.

Try putting it last:

```
 # other rescues in here.
 rescue => exception
  exception.backtrace.each { |trace| puts trace }
 end # this one is the last, only executed if none of the others are
```

If the problem is that you're not sure which class is being raised, just use something like pry to debug the `exception.class`